# The neighborhood $U$ of the identity generates a connected Lie group $G$. Proof check.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, lie-groups, topological-groups

I want to check if my proof is correct.

Consider the subgroup $H$ of $G$ which generated by $U$. Then it's enough to show that $H=G$. But, if $H\neq G$, then $G$ can be written as a disjoint union of cosets $gH$ i.e. $G=\cup_{g\in G} gH$. So, it's enough to show that $gH$ is open since in that case we will write $G$ as a disjoint union of two non-empty open sets $H$ and $\cup_{g\neq e\in G}gH$ i.e.
$$G=H\cup(\cup_{g\neq e\in G}gH)$$
Which contradicts the fact that $G$ is connected.

To show that $gH$ is open it's enough to show that $H$ is open since $gH$ is just the image of $L_g(H)$ where $L_g:G\to G$ is an automorphism of $G$ given by $L_g(a)=ga$. But, $H$ is open since $H=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U^n$.

*Does it work?*

Comment: You just need to prove that indeed $H=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U^n$, but it seems fine.

Comment: I just want to check that $U^n$ is open. I will do it by induction. For $n=1$, it is our assumption. For the induction step, if $x\in U^n$, then $x=ab$ where $a\in U$ and $b\in U^{n-1}$. So, $a^{-1}x=b\in U^{n-1}$. Since $U^{n-1}$ is open, we can easily conclude that $U^{n}$ is open. Indeed, if $a^{-1}x\in V\subset U^{n-1}$ then $x\in aV\subset U^{n}$ where $V$ and $aV$ are open.

Comment: Or, something along your line of thought, $U^n=\cup_{g\in U}gU^{n-1}$ and each $g\in G$ acts as a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have proved is that connected Lie groups have no proper, non-trivial, open subgroups. Which is true. And then applied it to the special case $H=\langle U\rangle$. I see no obvious problem with it.